# Gmail API thread_ids

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api

I forwarded an email from the test@gmail.com account to the email@gmail.com account. In the email@gmail.com account, I receive the email, process it and save the ids. Afterwards, I want to using the gmail API, send an email back as a reply using test@gmail.com, however, the thread id I saved earlier is different from the thread id inside that account. How when processing the email in the email@gmail.com account, can I get the original thread id, present in the test@gmail.com account?

I need the original thread_id/email_id